# What is the significance of using next() after sorting and limiting the cursor of mongo db?

Tags: mongodb

```
var cursor = db.processes.find({"status" : "READY"});
ps = cursor.sort({"priority" : -1}).limit(1).next();
```

In the above code if I do not use `next()` at last then also I get the same result in ps. So what is significance of using `next()` at last ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case it has no difference. This is because of `limit(1)` that you add in your second line.

But if you will remove it and just use `ps = cursor.sort({"priority" : -1}).next();` this will still return you only one element and move the cursor to the next element. So when you will run the same query `ps = cur...` one more time it will return the next one element. This will continue till you will exhaust the cursor and you will get something like `error hasNext: false` (or you the cursor will timeout, wait for a couple of minutes without touching it and it will timeout).

On the other hand if you will run `ps = cursor.sort({"priority" : -1})` you will get all the results (actually `DBQuery.shellBatchSize` of them).

Read more about [next here:](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.next/)

> Returns: The next document in the cursor returned by the
>   db.collection.find() method.